# Laravel LinkedIn Login with JSAPI and Angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, oauth, linkedin-api

I have an Android app built with Angularjs and Ionic. Backend is Laravel API. I need to implement Login with LinkedIn. I cannot use redirects so I am using LinkedIn JSAPI. I followed the [tutorial](https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens) to exchange JSAPI and get accessToken on the server but I am not able to get it to work. Has anyone implemented this? I want to fetch user details on server not in the frontend.

Comment: You should show what you've tried. Please show us the code and be more specific ;)

Comment: The code is exactly what is mentioned in the link I shared.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using LinkedIn's native Android SDK for simpler handling of Login with LinkedIn in an Android environment, rather than the JS SDK.

More details available here:
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk